# Oracle EBS Alert Mechanism

Tags: oracle, oracle-ebs

I have no knowledge on Oracle EBS and Oracle Alert mechanism.
My understanding is that Oracle Alert works just like database trigger.

Will Oracle Alert fire when database updates/inserts happen from the back-end?
We have observed alert is only firing for transactions front end and not running for back-end updates?

Is it guaranteed that just like a Trigger, EBS Alert will fire on every update to the record?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My understanding is that Oracle Alert works just like database trigger.

Yes, it is somewhat like a database trigger created from the Front-End Application. To explain further, there are two types of Oracle Alerts, Periodic and Event Alerts.

1. Periodic Alerts are alerts have a specific schedule and run according to a set period and time.
2. Event Alerts are alerts that only send notifications whenever inserts or updates have been performed on a table from the Front-End Application.

Take note that for Event Alerts, the triggering table must be setup in Oracle EBS' Application Object Library (called an Application Table).

> Will Oracle Alert fire when database updates/inserts happen from the backend?

No. Taking this line from [Krishna Reddy](http://krishnareddyoracleapps.blogspot.com/2012/06/oracle-alerts-is.html):

> Oracle Alerts can only be triggered from an application that has been
>   registered in Oracle Applications. Alerts cannot be triggered via SQL
>   updates or deletes to an Alert activated trigger.

To add more context, Oracle Alert is a simple and efficient way to give you an immediate view of the critical activities in your Oracle Application. It helps Business Users / Administrators be on top of important or unusual business events you need to know about via E-Mail. It can also automate a process depending on the user’s response.

Some weaknesses and limitations though, is that Oracle Alert cannot process rows up to more than around 50, and its Report Layout has a text-based design and does not support HTML. Also, the text width is also limited.

Check out the [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A60725_05/html/comnls/us/alr/evntalr.htm) and [this good article](https://anilpatchava.blogspot.com/2013/10/alerts-introduction-oracle-alerts-is.html) about Oracle Alerts.